# method to display float in datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime, floating-point

I need a method in c# that makes me a string that look like a datetime out of a double/float.

for example

1.5 -> 01:30
2.8 -> 02:48
25.5 -> 25:30 (note: don't display as day, display full hours even its more than 24)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
string ToTime(double hours)
{
    var span=TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
    return string.Format("{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
        (int)span.TotalHours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
}
```

Or if you don't want seconds:

```
string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", (int)span.TotalHours, span.Minutes)
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like you don't want a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) - you want a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x);
```

or

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(x);
```

(depending on your exact requirement).

Note that "2.8" won't be *exactly* 2.8, so you may not get *exactly* the result you expect - for the normal reasons of floating point bases etc.

Although there's no custom formatting for `TimeSpan` values in currently released version of the framework, it's coming in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Jon, please stop skeeting me ;-)